# Integration Amazon Cognito with Social Login - Apple Touch Id

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, touch-id

I'm trying to implement Federated Sign In with Amazon Cognito using different providers. I achieved to login with Facebook and Google but I'm facing issues with Sign In With Apple. We need to use the Touch Id feature from Apple but I didn't figure out how to do that. I couldn't find any clear documentation about how to achieve that.

If we use SDK, link as I did with other providers, it will open a browser and Apple will not approve do like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touch Id with Apple is working normally now. It seems was some problem with SDK.

Comment: How you implemented this? I don't find any doc explaining how to implement social login without hosted UI?